# sending a filepath in json string to PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have to send a filepath via. a json string to my controller in codeigniter

I have already modifed codeigniters config to accept a json string as a paramater

example:

www.mysite.com/controller/function/{"foo":"bar","hello":"word"}

This works fine.

But now I want to pass in a file path like this

www.mysite.com/controller/function/{"path":"D:\my\path\to\file.txt","foo":"bar"}

When i urldecode the paramter sent to the function in the controller I get a nice string looking like this

{"path":"D:\my\path\to\file.txt","foo":"bar"}

When I try to json_decode this I get

NULL

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it's JSON, you have to consider that your directory separators are going to be treated as escapes by the JSON parser. JSON has **NO** idea that you're passing in a path. It's just going to see a bunch of unnecessary escapes. The JSON must be syntactically valid, which means:

```
{"path":"D:\\my\\path\\to\\file.txt","foo":"bar"}
```

Note the doubled-up backslashes. Also note that on Windows, PHP is smart enough to accept forward slashes as the path separators as well, and will auto-convert for your as necessary. `d:/my/path/to/file.txt` would work just as well.

Comment: Thank you, ofc. this was the problem :) such a simple thing